# VS Code: Prevent Prettier from overwriting formatting from Better Align

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, prettier

I've gone through formatting settings and stack overflow posts, I've toggled with a bunch of different settings and can't seem to find an answer to this.

Two VS Code extensions come into play here: Prettier and Better Align. I want to use Prettier to format my code generally, and Better Align to align certain pieces of my code. But Prettier overwrites any changes that I make with Better Align.

For example:

After running Better Align, before running Prettier:

```
<ReactMapGL
          {...this.props.viewport}
          zoomEnabled          = {true}
          showUserLocation     = {true}
          mapStyle             = {this.props.mapStyle}
          mapboxApiAccessToken = {process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
          onViewportChange     = {(viewport) => {
            this.props.updateViewport(viewport);
          }}
        >
```

Then, after running Prettier:

```
<ReactMapGL
          {...this.props.viewport}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          showUserLocation={true}
          mapStyle={this.props.mapStyle}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
          onViewportChange={(viewport) => {
            this.props.updateViewport(viewport);
          }}
        >
```

Is there a setting in Prettier that overlooks the alignment formatting? Alternatively, is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check the [Ignoring Code](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) function of Prettier.

Basically, just add comment `prettier-ignore` before the code to which you applied Better Align and which you want to prevent Prettier from formatting when saving the file.

> A JavaScript comment of `// prettier-ignore` will exclude the next node
> in the abstract syntax tree from formatting.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> matrix(
>   1, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 0,
>   0, 0, 1
> )
>
> // prettier-ignore
> matrix(
>   1, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 0,
>   0, 0, 1
> )
> ```
>
> will be transformed to:
>
> ```
> matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
>
> // prettier-ignore
> matrix(
>   1, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 0,
>   0, 0, 1
> )
> ```

Comment: it isn't ideal, but agreed that `// prettier-ignore` is a good, simple solution

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is disabling formatOnSave and leaving the alignment for after formatting, I'm afraid.